# Python Selenium web scraping driver.get does not return on dynamic website

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, aws-lambda

I am trying to get runner statistic on ITRA website. For example, I am going to visit the following URL and then get the table content into a pandas dataframe.

URL: https://itra.run/runners/583078-kris-brown

Table: The table under the text "ITRA Performance Index"

I use python 3.6 + Selenium to do the job for me.

```
from selenium import webdriver
..
..
driver.get('https://itra.run/runners/583078-kris-brown') <--- wait indefinitely
```

All good when I test in the local computer. However, when I move it to AWS Lambda, the driver.get waits indefinitely and timeout finally.

Next, I change the URL into https://www.google.com, the driver.get run on Lambda can get me the html page source without problem. So, the code has no problem, the only thing is the ITRA web site. There is something blocking my selenium driver.get.

Next, I try to use urllib.request to get the ITRA page again.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
page = urlopen('https://itra.run/runners/583078-kris-brown')
```

This time, I know this is actually a dynamic webpage. Because I see there are many scripts html code.

May I know how can I load the dynamic webpage completely and get the table data?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title> - ITRA</title> 
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="csrf-token" content="e32JYo0XlGGc4Hick6nlmC52cB4f7NPm82vzrafh">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style> textarea { resize: none; } </style>
<style>
.twitter-typeahead,
.tt-hint,
.tt-input,
.tt-menu{
width: auto ! important;
font-weight: normal;
}
</style>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/pricing.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/composants.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/leaflet.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" ></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.2.1/css/ol.css">
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=vueRecaptchaApiLoaded&render=explicit" async defer></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.2.1/build/ol.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
<navbar></navbar>
<socialnetworksitra></socialnetworksitra>
<div >
<app></app>
</div>
<footercomponent></footercomponent>
</div>
<script src="/js/app.js?id=7223b0415ef9ffa136e5"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-recaptcha@latest/dist/vue-recaptcha.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-recaptcha@latest/dist/vue-recaptcha.min.js"></script>
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-4373731-16', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
<!-- facebook connect -->
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
appId      : '{your-app-id}',
cookie     : true,
xfbml      : true,
version    : '{api-version}'
});
FB.AppEvents.logPageView();   
};
(function(d, s, id){
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v6.0&appId=296638871419734&autoLogAppEvents=1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// create a js variable to hold the APP_ENV variable from php 
const env = 'production';
// Disable console log on production
if (env === 'production') {
console.log = function () 
{}
;
}
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$(".more").hide();
jQuery('.button-read-more').click(function () {
// one at a time
$('.more').hide();
$('.less').removeClass('active');
$(this).closest('.less').addClass('active');
$(this).closest(".less").next().stop(true).slideDown("1000");
});
jQuery('.button-read-less').click(function () {
$(this).closest('.less').removeClass('active');
$(this).closest(".less").next().stop(true).slideUp("1000");
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the way to get the dynamic content from websites is to check XHR request on network tab of chrome when you press F12. You should check this when you make any action that changes the data.

The XHR request are mostly REST API calls that fetch data from server using GET/POST request. The output would be html or JSON response.

From the XHR request you can see form data, URL,  output.
You can simulate the same thing using POSTMAN to test it, and then use python request module to make GET/POST calls.

Comment: I have just tried the F12 function and on the network tab. I found that the data is in https://itra.run/runner/583078/results. It looks like a json object instead of html code. So, I should post a request to this URL instead, and then read the json and extract the data. right?

Comment: By using the XHR method, I am able to get the table in json format and then use pd.read_json to get a pandas dataframe. It eliminates the need of selenium. Thanks alot!